# How to call Db view file in repository pattern?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-core, ef-code-first, repository-pattern

I am creating a view file in SQL Server as shown in the image below.

[image]

and I created a model to get results from this view:

```
public class FactALLCousumption : BaseEntity, IAggregateRoot
{

    public double sumActiveImportTotal { get;  set; }
    public DateTime hour { get;  set; }
    public int fullDateAlternateKey { get;  set; }
}
```

But I can't call this view in my repository. My repository code is bellow:

```
public class FactCousumptionRepository: GenericRepository<FactCousumption>, IFactCousumptionRepository
{
    public DbContext _dbContext;

    public FactCousumptionRepository(BaseDbContext context) : base(context)
    {
        _dbContext = context;           
    }

    public async Task<FactALLCousumption> GetTotalAllCousumption()
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In EF Core 2.2 or 2.1, you could use Query types.

According to the screenshot and the model to be used for the View you provided , I make a simple working demo like below , you could refer to and make the modification as per your demand:

1.Model

```
 public class FactCousumption
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public double SumActiveImportTotal { get; set; }
    public int DateKeyId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("DateKeyId")]
    public Dim_Date Dim_Date { get; set; }
    public int TimeAltKeyId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("TimeAltKeyId")]
    public Dim_Time Dim_Time { get; set; }
    public int TariffKeyId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("TariffKeyId")]
    public Dim_Tariff Dim_Tariff { get; set; }
}

public class Dim_Date
{
    [Key]
    public int DateKey { get; set; }
    public int FullDateAlternateKey { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public ICollection<FactCousumption> FactCousumptions { get; set; }
}

public class Dim_Time
{
    [Key]
    public int TimeAltKey { get; set; }
    public DateTime Hour { get; set; }
    public ICollection<FactCousumption> FactCousumptions { get; set; }
}
 public class Dim_Tariff
{
    [Key]
    public int TariffType { get; set; }
    public string TariffName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<FactCousumption> FactCousumptions { get; set; }
}
```

2.Create SQL View

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[View1]
AS  SELECT SUM(FactCousumption.SumActiveImportTotal) AS consumption ,Dim_Time.HOUR,Dim_Date.FullDateAlternateKey,Dim_Tariff.TariffName
  FROM FactCousumption INNER JOIN
        Dim_Date ON FactCousumption.DateKeyId = Dim_Date.DateKey INNER JOIN
        Dim_Time ON FactCousumption.TimeAltKeyId=Dim_Time.TimeAltKey INNER JOIN
        Dim_Tariff ON FactCousumption.TariffKeyId=Dim_Tariff.TariffType
  GROUP BY Dim_Date.FullDateAlternateKey, Dim_Time.HOUR ,Dim_Tariff.TariffName
```

3.The model that is used for the view , note : the property name in model should be consistent with those in the view

```
public class FactALLCousumption
{
    public double consumption { get; set; }
    public DateTime hour { get; set; }
    public int fullDateAlternateKey { get; set; }
}
```

4.DbContext , create  a DbQuery property in my DbContext to consume the view results inside the Model and set up the View especially if you have different view name than your Class.

```
 public DbQuery<FactALLCousumption> FactALLCousumption { get; set; }

 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
 {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Query<FactALLCousumption>().ToView("View1");
 }
```

5.Finally you can easily get the results of the View like this.

```
public async Task<FactALLCousumption> GetTotalAllCousumption()
{
        var result = await _context.FactALLCousumption.FirstOrDefaultAsync();

        return result;
}
```

**Note**: It's worth noting that DbQuery won't be/is not supported anymore in EF Core 3.0. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types)